# How to remove particular mesh points in the given plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, mesh, plot-themes

I am using this code

```
Clear[a, b, f, dx, dy];
{a, b} = {2, 2};
{dx, dy} = {Subdivide[0, a, 3], Subdivide[0, b, 3]};
f[x_, y_] = {x, y};


p1 = ParametricPlot[f @@ {x, y}, {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}, Mesh -> {dx, dy}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Black, 
 Point[f @@@ Tuples[{dx, dy}]]}, Frame -> False, Axes -> False,  PlotStyle -> None];


p2 = Graphics[ {{Thickness[0.9], Yellow, Opacity[1],CapForm["Butt"],Line[{{0.4, 0.75}, {0.9, 0.75}}]}, 
{Inset[Style["word1", 20], {0.67, 1.28}]   } , 
{Inset[Style["word2", 20], {0.67, 0.58}]   }  }  ];


 Show[{p1, p2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.3}, {0.3, 1.6}} ]
```

and the result is the left picture below

[image]

**My question:** I want to remove only those two mesh points inside my yellow box, and then put my words instead of them (something like the right plot); how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put everything in the `Epilog`.

```
p2 = {PointSize[Medium], Black, 
   Point[f @@@ Tuples[{dx, dy}]], {Thickness[0.9], Yellow, Opacity[1],
     CapForm["Butt"], 
    Line[{{0.4, 0.8}, {0.9, 0.8}}]}, {Inset[
     Style["word1", 20], {0.67, 1.33}]}, {Inset[
     Style["word2", 20], {0.67, 0.66}]}};

ParametricPlot[f @@ {x, y}, {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}, Mesh -> {dx, dy}, 
 Epilog -> p2, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> None, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1.3}, {0.3, 1.6}}]
```

[image]